# Similar rule in EditorConfig as StyleCop SA1000

Tags: stylecop, editorconfig

As title said, our team want to enforce the order of each elements, similar to StyleCop SA1000. Also we would like to have the elements ordered from public to private.

Is there any similar rule in editorconfig? If not, will StyleCop rules work with editorconfig?